# How pass BufferedInputStream or object that contains other object in JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I want to directly pass BufferedInputStream in JAX-WS

I created this webservice

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "upload")
public String upload(@WebParam(name = "file") BufferedInputStream file) {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    return null;
}
```

But, when I add the webservice client, IDE generate a own webservice class in ws package.

```
package com.ws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bufferedInputStream")
public class BufferedInputStream
    extends FilterInputStream
{


}
```

And the upload method in the service only accept this class, not the java.io.BufferedInputStream, so I cannot pass the file to the service.

Then I change the webservice to this, and create my own class to contain the BufferedInputStream, so that I can set the java.io.BufferedInputStream into myFile.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "upload")
public String upload(@WebParam(name = "myFile") MyFile myFile) {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    return null;
}



package com.ws;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

public class MyFile {
    private java.io.BufferedInputStream bis;

    public MyFile(BufferedInputStream bis)
    {
        this.bis=bis;
    }

    public BufferedInputStream getBis() {
        return bis;
    }

    public void setBis(BufferedInputStream bis) {
        this.bis = bis;
    }
}
```

But, when I add webservice client, IDE generate com.ws.BufferedInputStream and uses it in MyFile.

```
package com.ws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myFile", propOrder = {
    "bis"
})
public class MyFile {

    protected BufferedInputStream bis;

    public BufferedInputStream getBis() {
        return bis;
    }
    public void setBis(BufferedInputStream value) {
        this.bis = value;
    }

}
```

So I correct the type manually.

```
package com.ws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myFile", propOrder = {
    "bis"
})
public class MyFile {

    protected java.io.BufferedInputStream bis;

    public java.io.BufferedInputStream getBis() {
        return bis;
    }
    public void setBis(java.io.BufferedInputStream value) {
        this.bis = value;
    }

}
```

But, when I rebuild the project. All java.io.BufferedInputStream will change back to com.ws.BufferedInputStream

How to modify the code to pass BufferedInputStream to jax-ws?

---

Now I follow this tutorial to create JAXB class

https://netbeans.org/kb/74/websvc/jaxb.html

I use this as the WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">

  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://khameleon.anosym.com/service">
    <bindings scd="~tns:bufferedInputStream">
        <class ref="java.io.BufferedInputStream"/>
    </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

But it prompt me "Error while compiling Schema(s)" when I generate Java code. Is there any tool can help me generate the WSDL file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to define jaxb bindings and supply this binding to the wsimport during the point of generating the ws artifacts.

An example of ws binding is:

https://github.com/marembo2008/khameleon/blob/master/khameleon-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/jaxws/xconfigure-data-binding.xml

And if you are using maven, you can use the jaxws-maven-plugin.

https://github.com/marembo2008/khameleon/blob/master/khameleon-core/pom.xml#LC44

Hence you can also declare your binding file for BufferedInputStream as:

```
<bindings scd="~tns:bufferedInputStream">
  <class ref="java.io.BufferedInputStream"/>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I use you example's WSDL format to generate class, but compile error

Comment: Can you post the wsdl you are using

Comment: This WSDL file posted at the end of question.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">

  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://khameleon.anosym.com/service">
    <bindings scd="~tns:bufferedInputStream">
        <class ref="java.io.BufferedInputStream"/>
    </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>`

Comment: You are using the wrong namespace: change xmlns:tns="http://khameleon.anosym.com/service" to the namespace of of the schema types (which for simple wsdl, may be the same as the schema for the entire wsdl). On the wsdl find the targetNamespace namespace declaration

Comment: I try many different namespace, they also not valid, I think the whole WSDL file is not valid, now I convert the file to byte[] to send to service